# swift UIWebView Into Alert

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uialertview

i want to open an alert within an UIWebView programmatically. So i created a message, an action and i setted my own size to UIAlert.

The following is my code:

```
var title = "Pp"
    var message = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    var cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Chiudi", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: nil)
    var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.90)
    alert.view.addConstraint(height);
    alert.view.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height * 0.90

    var web = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.8 - 15, height: self.view.frame.size.height * 0.8 - 95))

    let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.it")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    web.scalesPageToFit = true
    web.loadRequest(request)
    alert.view.addSubview(web)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Ok, my result is something like this
[image]

I dont really like that button's position over the WebView, it should be below the view.

Thanks at all in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You should just add another set of `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n` to `var message = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";` so it becomes `var message = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n”;`. The UIWebView doesn’t seem like it’s affecting the height of the UIAlertController, it looks like the message is. This should fix the problem, although you should consider changing all the `var`s to `let`.

Here is what the full code should look like:
    let title = "Privacy Policy"
    let message = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Chiudi", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: nil)

let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.90)
alert.view.addConstraint(height);
alert.view.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height * 0.90

let web = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.8 - 15, height: self.view.frame.size.height * 0.85 - 95)) // take note that right here, in the height:, I’ve changed 0.8 to 0.85 so it should look more consistent on the top and bottom
let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.it");
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!);
web.loadRequest(request);

web.scalesPageToFit = true
web.loadRequest(request)
alert.view.addSubview(web)
alert.addAction(cancel)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That should be all it needs :)

Comment: is this is the best approach to get WebView Inside AlertView ?